# How can I can program a calendar in Android?

Tags: android, calendar, styles

I have to program in Android a calendar that shows a month, that I can slide horizontally to show other months. I tried with the calendarview but it's an infinite scrollable calendar, I need to show a month at once.
One more thing: how can I change the color and the style of a single day in the calendar? For example, to show in which days there are events and in which not.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I've write with `gridView`, you can handle all thing and add swipe and other thing, you can try that if you don't get any better solution

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? Thanks

Comment: No, I can't. source of code is for my company and i can't share with you, but if you want help in any step of that I can help you, you start if have a problem, tell me

Comment: Ok, don't worry, I will try to do something